# Converting LINQ Projection from C# to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

C# LINQ Query

```
position.CoordinateList = FenceItem.FencePosts.AsEnumerable().Select(coord => new FenceCoordinate
                        {
                            PosLat = coord.PLatitude,
                            PosLong = coord.PLongitude
                        }).ToList();
```

VB Query

```
 Dim position As New FencePosition()
                        position.CoordinateList = FenceItem.FencePosts.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(coord) New FenceCoordinate() With { _
                         .PosLat = coord.PLatitude, _
                         .PosLong = coord.PLongitude _
                        }).ToList()
```

But in VB its giving following error,

```
Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of NMI.GeoFenceData.GeoDecision.FenceCoordinate)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of NMI.GeoFenceData.GeoDecision.FenceCoordinate'.
```

Comment: what Type is `FencePosition.CoordinateList`?  VS seems to think it is an array not list

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but couldn't resist. Here is the equivalent VB.NET code on top of my head:

```
position.CoordinateList = FenceItem.FencePosts
.AsEnumerable()
.Select(Function(coord) New FenceCoordinate With 
    {
        .PosLat = coord.PLatitude,
        .PosLong = coord.PLongitude
    })
.ToList()
```